# Returning Large Files With FastAPI and StreamingResponse runs out of memory because read() loads whole file into memory

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I've been working with FastAPI and I've noticed that distributing large files is an issue. While I can upload them to a FastAPI server:

```
    async with aiofiles.open(temp_file_path, 'wb') as f:
        while chunk := await file.read(CHUNK_SIZE):
            await f.write(chunk)
```

I cannot manage to distribute the files.

For distributing:

```
file = open(filename, "rb", buffering=10485760)
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + filename}
return StreamingResponse(content=io.BytesIO(file.read()), media_type="application/octet-stream", headers=headers)
# For context, StreamingResponse is from starlette.responses.StreamingResponse
```

I tried using the buffering argument, however it looks like this argument just doesn't manage to work.

How can I return a file procedurally so that all of it isn't loaded into memory at once?

Comment: It's also worth nothing that StreamingResponse accepts an generator directly as well, so if you want to read a resource in chunks instead of reading it into memory and it has a file-like interface, you can do it as shown in the manual: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#using-streamingresponse-with-file-like-objects - But as this is a file, just use FileResponse as you discovered.

Comment: Thank you so much! The hacky workaround that I did involved downloading a full file and then serving it to the client rather than streaming it. I made something that yields the file in parts and then serves it procedurally and it works so much better. My code is working like 100% better lol.

Answer (score 2):

Most definitely not my best and brightest moment!!!!
FileResponse takes a path parameter, which downloads millions of times faster. If I download the file, then specifying a path and simply letting FastHTTP serve the file works.